# php preg_match - unexpected output

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this code:

```
<?php

$str = '<form name="signIn" action="http://example.com" method="post">' .
 '<input type="hidden" name="myname" value="xyz"><input type="hidden"   name="yourname" value="abc">' .
 '</form>';

preg_match('/<form name=\"sign_in|signIn\" (.+)>(.+)<\/form>/Us', $str, $m);

print_r($m);
```

The output of this code is this:

```
Array
(
 [0] => signIn" action="http://example.com" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="myname" value="xyz"><input type="hidden" name="yourname" value="abc"></form>
 [1] => action="http://example.com" method="post"
 [2] => <input type="hidden" name="myname" value="xyz"><input type="hidden" name="yourname" value="abc">
)
```

What I don't understand is why doesn't cell 0 in the output array start with `<form name="`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the alternative in a group:

```
preg_match('/<form name="(?:sign_in|signIn)" (.+)>(.+)<\/form>/Us', $str, $m);
```

But you'd better use a parser. Regex and HTML are not good friend!